# Apache2 svn Multiple repositories

Tags: apache, svn

I goggoled a lot about the feature to have multipe repositorie in different location on a server with apache2.
All describe to modify `/etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf` as below:

```
# Subversion - team A
<Location "/a">
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /svn/team-a
    SVNIndexXSLT "/svnindex.xsl"
</Location>

# Subversion - team B
<Location "/b">
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /svn/team-b
    SVNIndexXSLT "/svnindex.xsl"
</Location>
```

I tried to modify mine, but it does not work. Below my config:

```
<Location /Repo1>

  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /home/xxx/repositories/Repo1/

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/svn-users

</Location>

<Location /Repo2>

  DAV svn

  SVNParentPath /home/xxx/repositories/Repo2/

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/svn-users

</Location>
```

With this config none of two repositories work. If I enable 1 per time, the single repo works.

As you can see I want root repositories in different path: each root has different subrepositories.

Answer (score 0):

SVNParentPath != SVNPath

SVNParentPath is **parent-dir of all repos** for location, but **not repo**

Comment: I know. I have Repo1 that is the dir of many repos. Repo2 is the dir with different repos.

Comment: @LPs - show exact error-output (and used svn-command), I'm out of ideas now

Comment: I solved now. Something strange in rabbit svn. In terminal all is working well.

Answer (score 0):

At the end it was a problem on rabbit SVN. 
Using terminal all is ok.
Reinstalling RabbitSVN all is working well.